# Make a kubernetes pod connect with VPN running on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, docker, kubernetes, vpn

I have a pod running with k3d on a Windows machine (using Docker for Windows).

This pod have a Node Application running which needs connection with a VPN to consume an API provided through this connection, problem is: the Pod won't "see" the VPN Client running on Windows, so the API is always unreacheable.

Is it possible to make the pod connect with the VPN running on windows? If it is, what am I supposed to do? If it is not, what is the best solution?

Locally and running it through docker only the API works pretty fine.

Thanks!